# What does "run someone's plate" means?

Tags: idioms

In `Hot pursuit` movie, when `Randy` beats up the police officer who was looking after the girl, she (`Cooper`) says `I'll call you` while running. And `Randy` asks `How you gonna find me?`, Then `Cooper` answers.

> I'll run your plates!

I'm wondering what does it means.

`Randy` is a convicted felon who had an ankle monitor on him, if that helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "plates" being referred to here are likely license plates:

[image: Pennsylvania License Plate]

"Run your plates" is a set phrase, mostly used by police.

It generally describes a process of noting the license plate number, looking it up on a computer, and using the data there to figure out the name and address of the person who owns the car.

I've not seen this film, so I'm not familiar with this scene but I'm pretty sure this is what Cooper means.

Comment: I'm sure that's what her means! cause Cooper is a police officer. Thank you

Comment: My favorite Pennsylvania vanity plate to date: `UNIQUE6`.